# C4503 Warning but name doesn't seem that long

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2015

I'm getting a single issue of warning 4503 “decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated”.  There's only one in the entire large project, and this doesn't seem to be a particularly long name, as far as Boost templates go!

```
warning C4503: 'asio::detail::handler_ptr<Alloc_Traits>::handler_ptr': decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated
      with
      [
          Alloc_Traits=alloc_traits
      ]
```

Each version of the MSVC++ compiler extends the limit, so I expect by VS2015 it can handle Boost MPL without much hassle.

So why is the warning appearing on this (and only this), a relatively mundane template usage?  Any smart pointer of a class involving CRTP would be significantly longer.

I hesitate to just disable the warning in general because of other answers I've read on this site.  Especially with it being so rare, I'd like to have some idea what's going on with it.

Comment: The type you see there is 'abberviated' type - after taking all the typedefs into account. The full non-typedefed type is probably of mostrous length.

Comment: @SergeyA.  asio::detail::handler_ptr is simply derived from noncopyable, as are many other things.  alloc_traits might be the culprit, but I can't tell where it's really coming from.  I suppose it could be sufficiently circuitous.